# Extending IdentityUser with 2 classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, identity

In my project, I have a base `Repository` class defined like the following:

```
internal abstract class Repository<TDomain, TEntity> : IReadWriteRepository<TDomain>
    where TDomain : Model
    where TEntity : Entity
{
    public IQueryable<TDomain> Get()
    {
        var entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        return entities.Select(e => _mapper.ToDomain(e));
    }
}
```

As you can see, `TEntity` has a constraint and must be of type `Entity`

The `Entity` class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a `User` class which extends `IdentityUser<int>`

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>, Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This complains and gives an error that `Class 'User' cannot have multiple base classes: 'IdentityUser<int>' and 'Entity'`

Since my `Repository` is constrained to have `Entity` type I'm wondering how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface called `IEntity` and use the interface to define the constraint.

Then, implement the interface creating your abstract `Entity` class.

You can use `Entity` in your domain models with no problem, but in your User class, you can use the interface to make it an entity.

This way your user class and all your other domain models would satisfy the constraint.

Comment: I've added into the question an example implementation i.e `Get()` as you can see I'm trying to set the entity but with an interface this won't work as it must be a reference type